# Autofac Register Type without constructor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I have registered a type with `Autofac`, but the interface is always `null`. I dont know whether my implementation is correct. In the below code `_dbFactory` is always `null`. Please guide.

class library

```
 public class DatabaseHelper
{
    private IDatabaseFactory _dbFactory;

    public void ExecuteQuery()
    {
        using (var cmd = _dbFactory.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "Select *  from Employee";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

My **Console Application**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UpdateDependency();

        var dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper();

        dbHelper.ExecuteQuery();

        Console.Read();
    }

    public static void UpdateDependency()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.Register(c => new SqlFactory("Data Source=TEST;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True")).As<IDatabaseFactory>();

        var container = builder.Build();

        container.Resolve<IDatabaseFactory>();

        using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var app = scope.Resolve<IDatabaseFactory>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use a constructor?

Comment: @YacoubMassad, I dont want the client to pass type wen instantiating `DatabaseHelper`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Constructor Injection like this:

```
public class DatabaseHelper
{
    private IDatabaseFactory _dbFactory;

    public DatabaseHelper(IDatabaseFactory factory)
    {
        _dbFactory = factory;
    }

    ....
}
```

And then ask the container to resolve the `DatabaseHelper` instead of constructing it manually like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.Register(c => new SqlFactory("Data Source=TEST;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True")).As<IDatabaseFactory>();

    builder.RegisterType<DatabaseHelper>();

    var container = builder.Build();

    using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
    {
        var dbHelper = scope.Resolve<DatabaseHelper>();

        dbHelper.ExecuteQuery();

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Please note that you don't have to resolve `IDatabaseFactory` since the container automatically detects that it is a dependency of `DatabaseHelper` and will inject it automatically. This is called auto-wiring.

Comment: Thanks! That Works! Just for clarification. I am writing some common functionalities. I need to use `DatabaseHelper` at several places. So each and every time it seems to write `Autofac` container code instead of just instantiating `DatabaseHelper`